# How to track referrals when website is opened from mobile app

Tags: facebook, mobile, http-headers, instagram, referrals

I am wondering if it's possible to track referrals when my website is opened from mobile app? Is there any related information provided in *request headers*?

Particularly interested to know if it's opened from Facebook mobile app or Instagram mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the `utm_source` and `utm_medium` request parameters on your website. If they don't exist, then the best you're going to get is the user-agent of the device. Alternatively, if you're keen to always use bit.ly type shortened links, you could use a different one everywhere you post the link.